# Give Website Minimum Browser Size

Tags: html, css, browser

I use a lot of absolute elements in my website design so that it will mold to whatever browser dimensions are being used, but there is a minimum size that I want to use. In other words, I want my website to become compact as the browser is being resized smaller but at a certain point I want the overflow:auto attribute to kick in and force the user to see the whole page using scrolling instead of compacting the page further.

Any ideas? I tried putting in an empty table with specific dimensions into an element with overflow:auto, but that didn't work. I am not a terribly experienced web-designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### CSS

```css
html, body {
    min-width: 980px;
}
```

Comment: hm, that does give me the scroll bars when the browser gets to a certain size, but it doesn't prevent the absolute elements from contracting further.

Comment: Maybe I am just asking for too much?

Comment: Then you have to give the elements also a min-width of 980px